# How to remove black line from tabbar in Android?

Tags: android

I implemented tab bar in android application but i m facing a issue with black line.Can any one help me with this

[image]

```
 <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
         style="@style/tabhost">

    <LinearLayout   android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    >

        <TabWidget    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            style="@style/tabcontent"/>                

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>

<style name="tabhost">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#b1b1b1</item>
</style>

<style name="tabcontent">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">1dip</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to the associated java class:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);
```

([Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html#setStripEnabled%28boolean%29))